# Specified cast is not valid WebBroswer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I don't understand why I am getting a `Specified cast is not valid` error. It's happening on the `HtmlElement` variable `newElement`. The function `moreInfo()` is being called by a 
`System.Threading.Timer` callback.

```
    public void moreInfo()
    {
        HtmlElement newElement = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("order_billing_name");
        newElement.InnerText = nameBox.ToString();

        newElement = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("order_email");
        newElement.InnerText = emailBox.ToString();

        newElement = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("order_tel");
        newElement.InnerText = telephoneBox.ToString();

        newElement = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("order_billing_address");
        newElement.InnerText = addressBox.ToString();

        newElement = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("order_billing_zip");
        newElement.InnerText = zipBox.ToString();

        newElement = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("order_billing_city");
        newElement.InnerText = cityBox.ToString();

        newElement = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("order_billing_state");
        newElement.SetAttribute("value", stateBox.ToString());

        newElement = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("order_billing_country");
        newElement.SetAttribute("value", countryBox.ToString());


    }
```

Comment: It is a textBox on my windows form application.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that you're having an issue because you're trying to access a UI element from a non-UI thread.

You could replace your `System.Threading.Timer` with a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, which fires it's event back on the main thread.

Or you could try accessing the UI element on the main thread by calling `Invoke`:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => newElement.InnerText = nameBox.ToString()));
```

Comment: I found the reason. newElement is null even though it exists in the HTML the webBrowser is on. What does this mean?

Comment: The Html is here: https://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout <- View source